# Internet relay chat issues with Irssi on Ubuntu

Tags: irc

When I connect to Freenode in Irssi I get the following message.

```
 ERROR Closing link: (~zensky@cpe-76-95-243-246.socal.res.rr.com) [You
          must use TLS/SSL and authenticate via SASL to connect to freenode
          please visit https://irc.com/login/sso in order to create an account.
          SASL Configuration: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl - Webchat:
          https://webchat.freenode.net/]
16:43 -!- Irssi: Connection lost to chat.freenode.net
```

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: When was the last time you successfully connected to freenode? (Are you aware in general that "freenode" now is now a completely different network than the "freenode" 1 year ago?) And... have you read any of the webpages that are linked in that error message?